# Could, quantum mechanically, the Einstein field equations describe a single graviton?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity

There are various researches showing that the Maxwell equations quantum mechanically describe a single photon. Analogously one may ask, the Einstein field equations also quantum mechanically can describe a single graviton? Sorry if this question doesn't make sense somehow.

Comment: In general, when describing interacting theories at the quantum level, it does not make sense to study isolated particles. Because of self-interactions, a given particle is never truly "alone" (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_particle). Since the photon does not interact with itself, this issue does not come up (at least when matter is not present).

Comment: In the same way photons arise from quantizing electromagnetic waves (which satisfy Maxwell's equations), gravitons should arise from quantizing gravitational waves (which satisfy Einstein's equations). But that's precisely the goal we haven't reached, to build a quantum theory of gravity! This is how Feynman begins his study of GR in his book "Lectures on Gravitation", so I highly recommend reading the first 3 of those lectures if you're really interested.

Comment: Here we are not dealing with interacting theories, QED and QFT (yet). But as the next step, in principal, a single particle field (like Dirac field and single photon Maxwell field and the like) is subject to a process of second (canonical) quantization that is a formalism used to describe and analyze quantum many-body systems.

Answer (score -1):

Take this with a grain of salt, but that is what I belive at the moment:

Before being able to quantize gravity one linearizes the Einstein field equations to get the equations for gravitational waves. So if at all the equations which could describe a single graviton should be the [linearized Einstein field equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearized_gravity#Linearised_Einstein_field_equations).

However in opposition to Maxwells equations the linearized Einstein field equations probably do not describe the classical limit of infinite gravitons correctly, because gravitons interact with each other in opposition to photons. So it could well be that the classical limit of infinite interacting gravitons are in fact the full nonlinear Einstein field equations.